# Objc BAD_ACCESS when using a function to assign to a NSString property

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, exc-bad-access

Had this weird bug in my code and I was not able to solve it.

First I have this singelton class when I have a property called tempPassword.

```
 @private
NSString *_tempPassword;
 }

 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *tempPassword;

 +(User*)owner;
 -(void) setTempPassword:(NSString*)string;
```

The setTempPassword just takes this string and assigns it to tempPassword. The issue is that no matter what I did in the setTempPassword function, I always got BAD_ACCESS. Doest this have something to do with it being a predefined named and cant be used as I'm using it? Pulling my hair here...

Comment: Are you @synthesizing tempPassword?

Comment: yes tempPassword = _tempPassword

Comment: Do you override the setter or getter in the singleton?  EDIT: Stupid question.  Better: Why do you declare your override in the .h? It's unnecessary

Comment: yeah, i think so. if i name it setXxxx do I override it ?

Comment: You seem to have declared `-(void) setTempPassword:(NSString*)string;` as an override, but you don't need to declare setters or getters in the .h.  It's unnecessary.  Get rid of it and run again.

Comment: yeah... i did that after some ripping hair and screming. so that was the issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9011/discussion-between-codafi-and-chikuba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't mucking around with the string further than just setting it and getting (pun intended) out of the way, then there is no need to override the setter for it.  You mention that you already @synthesized the property, so overriding it is unnecessary anyways.  Just call:

```
[[MySingleton owner]setTempPassword:@"Password"];
```

and all will be right as rain, provided you remove those overrides from your code.